# What should I do with the extra wires in my switch box?

Tags: electrical

[image]Upon opening the ligthswitch box, I discovered that there are 3 pairs of black and white wires.  I have confirmed that one set goes to the light itself.  What should I do with the extra wires?
There are no plugs near by nor any other fixtures.
The pair on the right side go to the fixture, I have confirmed this.

Comment: Can you post a picture? It sounds like one is to the light, another is the feed, and the third is another fixture farther down the line. How were they all wired?

Comment: added photo for you!

Comment: Why do you think you need to *do* anything with them?

Comment: A friend, who is reluctant to actually do the work.... has loaned me his voltage tester thing.

Comment: I am changing the lightswitch out. from a basic switch to a timer.  The timer has three wires, red green and black.  I know what to do with those... its the extra set of black and white that are causing me issues.

Comment: You still haven't explained why they're "issues". Put them back where you found them. :)

Comment: so you are suggesting that I connect TWO BLACK wires to my lightswitch?

Comment: That's a very common scenario. The switch essentially breaks the hot leg of the circuit.

Comment: I wouldn't connect 2 wires to a switch.  I'd pigtail that.

Comment: LISTEN to what the others are telling you. There are NO "extra" wires in the box. They are doing something. Put it back the way it was.

Comment: I was able to confirm through use of a voltage tester, a volt meter. After checking the fixture and such - most of the posters are correct in stating that the "unexpected" wires are part of the branch.

Answer (score 2):

You should connect the new switch exactly as the old switch was connected. The "extra wires" likely feed the rest of the branch.

Comment: This! ...... Why in the world do folks who don't really know what they are doing so often think because there are not the wires they were expecting to find think there are "extra" wires. If they are in the box they are almost certainly NOT extra.

Comment: I have changed numerous light fixtures and a couple other switches.  These other switches did NOT have that third set of wires.  Can you see my confusion? Anyhow, borrowing my buddies equipment, and following his instructions - the switch is complete.  Thanks guys and gals

Answer (score 0):

The three sets of cables most likely are:

- Supply from the service panel (or something upstream)
- Supply going to the next thing downstream
- Switched power up to the light fixture itself

If you know which cable goes to the fixture itself, its black wire goes to the "load" side of the switch.  On a plain switch, it doesn't matter - either one.  On a smart switch, you have to check the manual.

If I'm right, the other two blacks tie together and also you'll have a pigtail (looks like there already is one) to the "line" side of the switch.  On a plain switch, that's the other one.   On a smart switch, check the manual.

*You can tie those blacks together with a "wire nut", similar to the black one that is already there, but I'd get new ones as they are better.  Nowadays they are color-coded by size, you'd want a yellow or maybe red.*

If a smart switch had a white, it would get tied in with neutral (the white wires bundled together).  If it has a green or bare wire, that goes to ground.  I don't see any ground in the picture.  You'd need to check the manual about what to do if you don't have ground.

Now I could be wrong, and the second one could be power to a second light fixture.  If so, the fixture will be constantly on.  Its black should be on the "load" side of the switch.

These questions tend to linger around and be found for years, so let me mention this to those who happen by in the future:  This sort of work is hazardous and is not for the uninformed novice.  Fortunately that is easily fixed with a variety of books out there,  find one that speaks your language, and enjoy!